# Нужны ли запятые в данных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация

Подойдите к банку, деньги забрать нужно. И наоборот — подойдите к банку, забрать деньги нужно. Мы уже десять минут стоим на остановке ждем автобуса — нужна ли тут запятая перед "ждем автобуса". Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) *Подойдите к банку, нужно забрать деньги. Нужно забрать деньги,  подойдите к банку.*  Взаимообусловленность предложений **не обозначена**, ставим запятую.

*Подойдите к банку — нужно забрать деньги. Нужно забрать деньги — подойдите к банку.* Взаимообусловленность предложений  **обозначена**, ставим тире.

Примечание: Инверсия (деньги забрать нужно) не является обоснованной.

2) **Стоим ждем автобуса.** Два глагола в личной форме (первый глагол со значением движения или положения). Это о**сложненная форма простого глагольного сказуемого (ПГС), запятой нет**. Примеры: ***сижу читаю, пойду посмотрю, пойдем посмотрим.***

При **дистантном положении** это однородные члены, запятая ставится. *Мы уже десять минут стоим на остановке, ждем автобуса*

Примечание

В зависимости **от контекста осложненное ПГС** может переходить в однородные сказуемые. Например:

(1) Рассказ: ***Стоим ждем автобуса***. Вдруг подъезжает машина... Паузы и запятой нет.

(2) Диалог: *Ты где сейчас? - Я на остановке. **Стою, жду** автобуса.* Делается пауза, ставится запятая.

Comment: *Стоим, ждем автобуса*. Запятая здесь возможна, более того - предпочтительна. Это совсем не то, что *пойду поставлю чайник*. Разницу чувствуете?

Comment: Еще одна к Вам пока просьба: уберите из Ваших комментариев фразу "разницу чувствуете". Вы ее часто употребляете, и не только  по отношению ко мне. Это разговорный, неуважительный вариант, совершенно недопустимый при общении с незнакомыми людьми.

Answer (score 0):

Стоим и ждём – однородные члены, разделяются запятой.

Comment: Подойдите к банку, деньги забрать нужно. И наоборот — подойдите к банку, забрать деньги нужно. А здесь верно поставлены запятые?

Comment: Здесь все верно.